# WDIO waitForExist not accepting large values when run with Cucumber?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I have a test environment where the element I want to wait for could take a minute to load, or more. I find that the `.waitForExist()` function is giving up after about 20 seconds, regardless of if I pass in `60000`, or `600000` as the millisecond value. It does not seem to throw an exception on the console.

I am using NPM and Cucumber to call the test like this:

`$ npm test -- --spec "features/b2c/campaigns/Viewing_a_campaign.feature" --cucumberOpts.tags="@smoke"`

What is the problem with supplying large values to this method?

**Note:** I don't have any problems with values `< 20000`.

Comment: It's pretty hard to debug with the information at hand. **[Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45331801/edit)** your question and add relevant info like: the snippet of code that does the waiting for you and all the related code (if you're using custom commands, or page objects), relevant timeout values from the `wdio.config.js` file. Else all answers will be `shots in the dark`. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks iamdanchiv

The issue was the `timeout` value in the `cucumberOpts` section of `wdio.config.js` which was set to `20000`, creating an upper limit for how long any individual step can run regardless of the wdio WaitFor commands.